# Buenas tardes ayudeme para poder definir mi data a frecuencia diaria

Tags: array, autoincremento, predicción, frecuencia

Estimados quiero definir la data en diario pero al correr el codigo me genera error.

```
df=pd.read_excel("/content/drive/MyDrive/Python/Base sintoma.xlsx",index_col="DATE",parse_dates=True)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

df.index

DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-15', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17', '2020-03-18',
               '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-21', '2020-03-22',
               '2020-03-23', '2020-03-24',
               ...
               '2020-12-06', '2020-12-07', '2020-12-08', '2020-12-09',
               '2020-12-10', '2020-12-11', '2020-12-12', '2020-12-13',
               '2020-12-14', '2020-12-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DATE', length=275, freq=None)

df.index.freq='d' 

ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency D

df.head()

           PopEst
DATE    
2020-03-15  105
2020-03-16  191
2020-03-17  116
2020-03-18  17
2020-03-19  73
```

Comment: ¿Cómo podemos ayudarte si no explicas que lenguaje estás usando? Debería ser la primera etiqueta que pones.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!